Syntax error when I add chown to sudoer file
I need a service account to be able to change the ownership of file and folders in a directory.  I checked the command to make sure it works at the command line, but visudo returns a syntax error when I add the command to the sudoer file.
The chown command:
device_monitor ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chown -R device_monitor:device_monitor /var/log/device-monitor/*

visudo returns the following syntax error:
/etc/sudoers:64:109: syntax error device_monitor ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chown -R device_monitor:device_monitor /var/log/device-monitor/*

If I remove both "-R" and "device_monitor:device_monitor" from the command, then it works.  Is there a way to include the -R flag and the owner and group in the sudoer file?  I'm using Ubuntu 24.04

You likely need to backslash-escape the colon character, : - see for example sudoers syntax error near line 1 while adding cmnd alias

backslash-escaping the colon character solved the problem.  Thank you @steeldriver
